# Columnas con la misma altura en Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo unas columnas cada una con un contenido, sin embargo como unas tienen más contenido que otras se ven más altas y en general se ve feo, ¿hay alguna forma de igualarlas todas para que tengan una misma altura? Intente ponerles clase que fuera `height:100%` pero no funciona o no sé si se lo coloqué al que era.

Éste es mi código:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
    <h2 class="text-orange">Nuestros Servicios</h2>
    <hr class="second">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail thumb-shadow">
      <img src="img/comunication.png" alt="Plataformas Customizables">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Comunicación, Análisis y apoyo</h3>
        <p class="text-justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum sint aperiam illum, sapiente et delectus iusto suscipit sed debitis rem error repellat. Corrupti eius voluptatum voluptatibus enim quasi autem! Nesciunt voluptatibus amet adipisci dolore ullam dicta numquam maxime eos soluta perferendis animi earum quidem, saepe. Repellendus, nostrum, sapiente. Tempore recusandae, rem accusamus, veritatis adipisci quibusdam eum at voluptate tempora eaque error odit eligendi autem sint consequatur sed similique, commodi quasi?
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Saber más.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail thumb-shadow">
      <img src="img/custom-web.png" alt="Plataformas Customizables">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Plataformas a la medida</h3>
        <p class="text-justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam error eum placeat deleniti animi magnam architecto quidem praesentium maiores alias sequi cum libero omnis nam optio asperiores dignissimos officia aut aliquam, aspernatur sunt fugiat! Commodi quasi dignissimos eos, voluptas debitis repellat magni. Eveniet minima debitis neque! Cum quaerat ducimus, corporis et nemo animi delectus nobis.
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Saber más.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail thumb-shadow">
      <img src="img/responsive-icon.png" alt="Diseño Responsivo">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Diseño Web a la vanguardia</h3>
        <p class="text-justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti sequi fugiat eum doloremque odit cumque dolores nobis quia voluptas tempora! Pariatur placeat distinctio itaque eius impedit natus suscipit, dignissimos culpa?
        </p>
        <button onclick="alr()" class="btn btn-danger">Saber más.</button>
        <div id="ntf"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail thumb-shadow">
      <img src="img/document-code.png" alt="Código Documentado">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Documentación y enseñanza</h3>
        <p class="text-justify">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, iste accusamus corporis amet repellat ullam quod, quas magni, vitae in, necessitatibus dolorum esse temporibus hic inventore voluptas saepe at officia aliquid. Voluptates sed nam aperiam, sapiente non expedita ipsa laborum commodi!
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Saber más.</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tal vez te pueda funcionar esta respuesta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688250/setting-equal-heights-for-divs-with-jquery

Comment: Muchas gracias funcionó

Comment: con la opción display flex se alinean de inmediato, pero se pierde la función responsive puesto que todas las columnas se agrupan en una única fila

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que cuando usas columnas en *Bootstrap*, estas no se miden la altura unas dependiendo de las otras.

Existen varias soluciones:

Edit: Encontré una solución más rápida y mejor que funciona bastante bien con *FlexBox*: Al padre (`row`), añádele la propiedad de `display: flex;`. Con eso los demás `div` dentro tendrán todos el mismo `height`, pero tendrás que solo incluir en el padre (`row`) los `div` que quieres que tengan la misma altura (separar el título de ese `div`) y adicionalmente, para lograr el efecto visual que deseas al los hijos directos darle el border (`col-`) o al contenido interior hacerlo a la altura máxima de este, ya que los hijos (`-col`) son los que se ven afectados por la igualación de altura.

Con *Javascript*, medir el alto de la columna más alta dentro del padre y ese mismo almacenarlo en una variable y asignárselo con *CSS* (una clase) al resto de los `div`.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var heights = $(".well").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".well").height(maxHeight);
});
```

*Foundation* es un *Framework* al igual que *Bootstrap* que tiene un script llamado ***equalizer***, que iguala las columnas como tú lo necesitas, siguiendo el método de la solución anterior.

También existe una variante de *equalizer* para *Bootstrap* creada por usuarios.

Te dejo el hilo donde lo discute en *StackOverflow en ingles*:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287206/same-height-column-bootstrap-3-row-responsive

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de tú proyecto podrías utilizar únicamente la propiedad `height:200px`,por ejemplo, para establecer el tamaño exacto de cada columna.
Si el contenido lo sobrepasa, podrías utilizar:

```
overflow:auto;
overflow:-x;
```

Que mostrará un scroll vertical.

Answer (score -3):

en bootstrap 4 a la columna que quieres ampliar la añades `class="card border-0"`

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Tu respuesta quedaría mucho mejor si la acompañas de un poco de código y ejemplos para que no sea solo texto. Un saludo :)

Comment: Te recomiendo dar una vuelta por el [Tour de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así ves como funciona el sitio, tambien es importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para poder elaborar una buena respuesta. Dicho esto, ademas no creo que esto responda a la pregunta.