# Cambia el tamaño de columna si supera la altura de la de al lado. BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, bootstrap, angularjs

Tengo una `row` dividido en dos columnas `md-6`, pero claro, si una de las columnas tiene mas contenido que otra se ve un lado más alto que otro.

¿ Es posible en Bootstrap hacer que si en una columna se supera la altura de la otra uno de los `div` contenido en esa columna pase a otra `row` con `md-12`?

Uso angular.

un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: con *altura* a que te refieres?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los cols de bootstrap solo sirven para el ancho de las columnas, no el alto.

Comment: Puedes hacer que las dos columnas sean del mismo tamano con `flex`. Checa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47255/33391